# Why doesn't new Date(ms) == (new Date()).setMilliseconds(ms)

Tags: javascript, date

I'd like to convert a timestamp into a date:

```
  status_transitions:
   { finalized_at: 1557419382,
     marked_uncollectible_at: null,
     paid_at: 1557419384,
     voided_at: null },
```

In particular, `paid_at: 1557419384`.  But when I try `new Date(1557419384)` I do not get the expected result.  If I use Date.setMilliseconds() I do.

What's especially strange is the output of `Date.setMilliseconds()`

```js
const ms = 1557419384;

const fromConstructor = new Date(ms);
const fromFn = new Date();
const strangeOutput = fromFn.setMilliseconds(ms);

console.log(`Milliseconds: ${ms}`);

console.log(`Output from setMilliseconds: ${strangeOutput}`);

console.log(`Date from new Date(ms): ${fromConstructor}`);

console.log(`Date using setMilliseconds(ms): ${fromFn}`);
```

The output of the code above is:

```
Milliseconds: 1557419384
Output from setMilliseconds: 1558978824384
Date from new Date(ms): Sun Jan 18 1970 18:36:59 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
Date using setMilliseconds(ms): Mon May 27 2019 12:40:24 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Why does creating a new date from a number not yield the same result of setMilliseconds()?  Also, why is the output from `setMilliseconds()` different than the actual milliseconds passed in?

I've read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) and they seem to imply there should be no difference between these two methods.

Comment: setMilliseconds returns "The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date."

Comment: By the way are you sure your timestamps are in ms? It would make more sense if they are in s, in which case your first date would be 2019-05-09T16:29:44.000Z. Clarifying this would be a good place to start.

Comment: It was seconds.  What I find humorous is that setting milliseconds was ultimately landing on a date far closer to today, enough so I didn't even realize it is roughly 20 days off.

Comment: 1557419382 ms is about 18 days :P... it seems that setMilliseconds just adds milliseconds to a date. Also new Date() instantiates a date object with the current time. So (new Date()).setMilliseconds(1557419382) is simply adding 18 days to the current date.

Comment: Because `new Date(...)` returns a Date object which is only ever `===` to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the example shown in the `setMilliseconds()` part of the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds).

```
var theBigDay = new Date();
theBigDay.setMilliseconds(100);
```

Running this right now, this gives me the value `1557421875100`.  Notice only the last three digits are 100.  Thus, it doesn't set the entire date object to 100, but only sets the milliseconds portion of the value.   The rest is coming from `new Date()`, which is the current UTC-based timestamp.

As far as why you don't get the expected result from `new Date(1557419384)`, that timestamp would appear to be in *seconds* rather than milliseconds.  Multiply the value by 1000 and it gives a more reasonable value.  ([Unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) are commonly expressed in whole seconds, which appears to be the case here.)

Comment: Also worth noting: Even if you declare two `Date` objects with the exact same time (e.g. `var a = new Date(100); var b = new Date(100);` you still won't see equivalence: `a == b; // false`. Because `Date` is a subclass of `Object` in JavaScript, two `Date`s are only equal if they reference the same instance in memory. Instead you should say `a.getTime() == b.getTime()`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'd also like to add that `(new Date()).setTime()` would be the equivalent function.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the output from `setMilliseconds()` different than the actual milliseconds passed in?

Check the docs more closely. [`setMilliSeconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds) has a "*Parameter:
A number between 0 and 999, representing the milliseconds.*" and its description states "*If you specify a number outside the expected range, the date information in the Date object is updated accordingly. For example, if you specify 1005, the number of seconds is incremented by 1, and 5 is used for the milliseconds.*".

So `new Date()` creates a date with the current time, and then you add your millisecond value to that.

> Why does creating a new date from a number not yield the same result of `setMilliseconds()`?
>   I've read the docs and they seem to imply there should be no difference between these two methods.

What you were looking for is [`setTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime). `new Date().setTime(millseconds)` creates an object that is equal to `new Date(milliseconds)`.

> When I try `new Date(1557419384)` I do not get the expected result.

As Matt Johnson noted, this value appears to be seconds not millisecond. Multiply it by 1000.